# SVG image circle stroke pattern is being cut on chromium

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, chromium

I have a crazy problem with SVG rendering in chrome/chromium (firefox works as expected).

I want to render a circle with empty fill but stroke containing a template but for some reason once I try to change screen resolution, circle strokes start to being cut off mostly on bottom/right edge. I can't identify why it happens. I'd like to know what should I do to prevent stroke from being cut, any help is welcome

**UPD** I don't care about IE and other outdated browsers. Just modern ones

Link to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/k8cbq4dv/

Screenshot is attached
[image]

The code itself:

```html
<div id="root">
    <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="background-color: rgb(204, 255, 204);">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="greenglaze" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="5" height="5">
                <image href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyiQU4yEPR1SIEF1mRiFOP1IMFoQ4s8y0vGJTRhRt4CbE4BaOuFEXrwEDWmI8ngIzbk_c&amp;usqp=CAU" width="5" height="5" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="12.91549430918954" fill="transparent" transform-origin="center" stroke="url(#greenglaze)" stroke-width="7.9" stroke-dasharray="100 0" stroke-dashoffset="-0" transform="rotate(-90, 0, 0)"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you reported it to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)?

Comment: @RobertLongson do you think it's chrome bug?

Comment: Please try removing the `transform-origin="center"` and use `transform="rotate(-90, 20, 20)` instead

Comment: @enxaneta it doesn't work

Comment: When testing with Chromium 112/Linux Mint, the bug did show up only sometimes: the stack snippet was always correct, the jsFiddle did show it on initial load, but on resizing the output iframe the missing pattern parts became visible.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this when I set my screen to its highest resolution, but not at lower resolutions - and it only fails to fill the bottom segment correctly (Chrome 112/Win10/x64).  Does this still reproduce when you reboot your machine at the new resolution (rather than changing resolution) - my guess is that some settings are getting cached on startup and don't get updated when resolution is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was late, but after some time of checking. It was understood that your `circle` is making that **cut** on your *donut*.

Because your `image` was set to `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, It will resize the content depend on the window size and it trigger that cut on the side of your image.

Maybe this could help or not, but using a **`stroke-miterlimit`** in your *`circle`* somehow fix the problem.

```html
<div id="root">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(204, 255, 204);">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="greenglaze" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="5" height="5">
        <image href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyiQU4yEPR1SIEF1mRiFOP1IMFoQ4s8y0vGJTRhRt4CbE4BaOuFEXrwEDWmI8ngIzbk_c&amp;usqp=CAU" width="5" height="5" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="11" stroke="url(#greenglaze)" fill="transparent" transform-origin="center" stroke="url(#greenglaze)" stroke-miterlimit="30" stroke-width="7px" stroke-dasharray="100 0" stroke-dashoffset="-0" transform="rotate(-90, 0, 0)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a suspicion, so the answer might still be incorrect. At least for me, the jsFiddle error did disapear.

It could be that Chromium has a problem with identifying the bounding box of the final grafic because it has to take into acount the width of a stroke. If it somehow miscalulates at that point, it might decide that some of the repetitions of the pattern will always be outside of the effective clip path and just not render them.

The solution then would be to not use a stroke-width and instead draw two circular paths combined:

```html
<div id="root">
  <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="background-color: rgb(204, 255, 204);">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="greenglaze" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="5" height="5">
        <image href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyiQU4yEPR1SIEF1mRiFOP1IMFoQ4s8y0vGJTRhRt4CbE4BaOuFEXrwEDWmI8ngIzbk_c&amp;usqp=CAU" width="5" height="5" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M 20 4.135
             A 15.865 15.865 0 0 0 20 35.865
             A 15.865 15.865 0 0 0 20 4.135 z
             M 20 10.035
             A 9.965 9.965 0 0 1 20 29.965
             A 9.965 9.965 0 0 1 20 10.035 z"
          fill="url(#greenglaze)" transform="rotate(-90, 20, 20)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous code didn't really solve the problem.

My English is not one of the best.

I did several tests here and what I saw as a solution would be the use of css.

```css
svg {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="background-color: rgb(204, 255, 204);">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="greenglaze" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="5" height="5">
        <image href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyiQU4yEPR1SIEF1mRiFOP1IMFoQ4s8y0vGJTRhRt4CbE4BaOuFEXrwEDWmI8ngIzbk_c&amp;usqp=CAU" 
               width="5" 
               height="5" 
               preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="20" 
            cy="20" 
            r="12.91549430918954" 
            fill="transparent" 
            transform-origin="center" 
            stroke="url(#greenglaze)" 
            stroke-width="7.9" 
            stroke-dasharray="100 0" 
            stroke-dashoffset="-0" 
            transform="rotate(-90, 0, 0)"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: UPD I expanded the snippet and solution doesn't work: https://imgur.com/a/Cn1yIwl

Comment: It really didn't work, I made a new solution proposal